# Xcode, Core Audio: How do I route the audio from the lineout to an application?

Tags: xcode, macos, core-audio

I need to make a Mac app that grabs the audio going to the lineout and renders it into memory.  Is it possible to do this with core audio and if so is it at a high enough level to do this simply or do I need to do like soundflower and create a virtual sound device. Do you know any reference where I can get do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JACK - just write a program with a jack input, run qjackctl and pipe whatever you want into it. This will give you more control than just looking at the lineout, not sure whether that's ideal or not for you.

Comment: Thanks but what I really need is to grab all the audio that is going to the lineout and render it into memory.  Inter application is not enough